# how to modify default command for TeX-command-master (ie, C-c C-c)?

Tags: latex, auctex

**Q:** how can I get `TeX-command-master` (`C-c C-c`) to default to `LaTeX` rather than `View`?

`TeX-command-master` dispatches to various commands, such as `LaTeX`, `BibTeX`, `View`, etc., almost none of which I use besides `LaTeX` and `BibTeX`.  In particular, I almost *never* use `View` via `TeX-command-master` (using `TeX-view` via `C-c C-v` instead), and it's annoying that `TeX-command-master` defaults to `View` after running `LaTeX`.

Instead, I'd like `TeX-command-master` never to default to `View`, but rather to `LaTeX` so that I can recompile without breaking my flow.

How would one change the default?  It seems rather extreme to edit out the `View` option from `TeX-command-list`, and I'm not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable controlling the default operation to do when AUCTeX assumes the output file is ready is `TeX-command-Show`.  The default value is of course `"View"`, but in your case you want to set it to `"LaTeX"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to change the behavior -- I've set it to `LaTeX`, but still get `View` as the default.

Comment: Did you restart Emacs?

Comment: Yup, you're right.  Starting a fresh session did the trick.