# How to disable DocView as default command in AUCTeX?

Tags: latex, auctex

When I'm writing a .tex file on emacs, I like to compile with pdflatex and then see the result on an external pdf viewer. The emacs manual says that I can use `C-c C-c` to launch any compilation method other than plain TeX, but the problem is that the default for `C-c C-c` is doc-view. This is a minor annoyance, because typing `pdflatex [Enter]` takes only a second, but still, I often wish that `C-c C-c` autocompleted to pdflatex. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Can `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)` help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how to modify default command for TeX-command-master (ie, C-c C-c)?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7970/how-to-modify-default-command-for-tex-command-master-ie-c-c-c-c).

Comment: There is no `pdflatex` command for `C-c C-c`, was it an error or did you customize TeX-command-list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to modify default command for TeX-command-master (ie, C-c C-c)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7970/how-to-modify-default-command-for-tex-command-master-ie-c-c-c-c)