# How to disable doc-view in AUCTex

Tags: latex, auctex, docview

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with AUCTex for LaTeX editing. The command C-c C-c allows me to easily compile the document with pdflatex. However, the second time I'm running C-c C-c, instead doc-view is launched (showing the resulting pdf).

This doesn't fit with my workflow. I use a different pdf viewer, and sometimes need to compile the document twice to get citations right etc.

Can I disable doc-view so that C-c C-c always executes pdflatex?

I've tried the solutions suggested here
[How to disable DocView as default command in AUCTeX?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/how-to-disable-docview-as-default-command-in-auctex?rq=1)
but had no effect.

This solution didn't work either
[how to modify default command for TeX-command-master (ie, C-c C-c)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7970/how-to-modify-default-command-for-tex-command-master-ie-c-c-c-c)
since I don't seem to have a TeX-command-master command installed (not available on M-x). C-c must be mapped to something else.

EDIT (Solved):
It turns out my problem was caused by me using Emacs latex mode rather than AUCTeX. After making sure AUCTeX is installed, it's invoked with LaTeX-mode, in contrast to Emacs latex mode that is invoked with latex-mode. The answer here [how to modify default command for TeX-command-master (ie, C-c C-c)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7970/how-to-modify-default-command-for-tex-command-master-ie-c-c-c-c) now solves my problem.

Comment: Check the value of `TeX-view-program-selection` variable.  Note opening doc-view isn't the default behavior, you somehow changed it in your init file.

Comment: That variable is not set for me. Also, I'm pretty sure I haven't changed the behaviour of C-c in anyway.

Comment: You have to evaluate it in a LaTeX buffer, it must have a value.  Which version of AUCTeX are you running?  Check the value of `AUCTeX-version` too (always in a LaTeX buffer).

Comment: I use the describe-variable, but there's no AUCTeX-version variable (I invoke the mode with LaTeX-mode, not actually positive it's AUCTeX at all).

Comment: When you open a LaTeX file, which menu do you see in your toolbar?  If you're using AUCTeX you should have, among other, `LaTeX` and `Command` (and last entry under `LaTeX` is `Report AUCTeX bug`, if you move pointer over this you'll see the tooltip `Problems with AUCTeX <version-here>? Mail us!`); instead with Emacs default latex mode you'll have `TeX` and `Text` menus.

Comment: I am an idiot :) I only thought I was using AUCTeX, when I was actually using Emacs Latex mode. Generally, the way to tell seem to be that Emacs Latex mode is invoked with latex-mode, whereas AUCTeX is invoked with LaTeX-mode. Thanks for your help, the missing variables is what got me suspicious.

Comment: I think most everyone who have used AUCTeX, or tried to use it, have experienced problems differentiating the built-in modes that have almost identical names.